# How to show which port is the database socket running by Linux command?

Tags: linux

I have three MySQL database sockets running on a Linux machine. By the cmd "sudo netstat -npl|grep mysql", I can find the ports and db sockets. But I need to match them one to one by using pid. 
Is there any cmd I can use to show the port number of a db socket directly in Linux?

Answer (score 1):

The output looks like this:

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3306            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3886/mysqld
```

The PID of the `mysqld` process is the number before `/mysqld`, i.e. `3886`.

Answer (score 1):

There's several different ways to do it, but for your purposes, I suggest simply looking at the output of the command you're already running.

```
$ sudo netstat -npl|grep mysql
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3306            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1124/mysqld
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     8713     1124/mysqld         /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

This is telling me that process `1124` is listening on 3306 and /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock